# Python: Unable to use BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I’m new to python. Why is this code not printing the top50 films?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning, module='bs4')

# website
url = "https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date="
year = input("Enter you're fav year for movie display: ")
output = url+year

# extracting the info from website
soup = BeautifulSoup(output, "lxml")

# Display the top 50 films
i = 1
movieList = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'lister-item mode-advanced'})

for x in movieList:
    div = x.find('div', attrs={'class': 'lister-item-content'})
    print(str(i) + '.')

header = x.findChild('h', attrs={'class': 'lister-item-header'})

 print('Movie: ' + str(header[0].findChild('a'))
      [0].contents[0].encode('utf-8').decode('ascii', 'ignore')) #and can someone tell me what is this.. because I’m following some guide. And i didn’t understand this line. 


i += 1
```

My current output is empty, can’t see anything on the terminal.

```
0/50 [00:00<?, ?it/s]1. 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "movie_recom.py", line 26, in <module> print('Movie: ' + str((header[0].findChild('a')) 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I need this output:

```
Most Popular Feature Films Released 2018-01-01:
 1. Movie: Avengers: Infinity War
 2. Movie: Venom
 3. Movie: A Quiet Place
 4. Movie: Black Panther
 5. Movie: I Feel Pretty
 6. Movie: Deadpool 2
 7. Movie: Ready Player One
 8. Movie: Super Troopers 2
 9. Movie: Rampage
10. Movie: Den of Thieves
```

and so on until 50.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your not getting any output before you haven't made a request to the url, try `r = requests.get(output)`, then `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')` then check the content of soup is the webpage html.

Comment: @davedwards my output: `python movie_recom.py 
Enter you're fav year for movie display: 2018
  0%|                                                       | 0/50 [00:00<?, ?it/s]1.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "movie_recom.py", line 26, in <module>
    print('Movie: ' + str((header[0].findChild('a'))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: For future reference, please **edit your question** to add details or clarifications. In particular code is very hard to read in comments due to the poor layout and formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't yet issued a request, then you can parse the response content.

This should get the full list:

```
r = requests.get(output)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

# Display the top 50 films
movieList = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'lister-item mode-advanced'})

for n, x in enumerate(movieList, 1):
    div = x.find('div', attrs={'class': 'lister-item-content'})
    print(str(n)+'.', div.find('a', href=True).text)
```

will return:

```
1. Aquaman
2. Mowgli: Legend of the Jungle
3. Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse
...
50. The Rookie
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys for the help but i already solved it.

```
i = 1
movieList = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'lister-item mode-advanced'})

for x in tqdm(movieList):
    div = x.find('div', attrs={'class': 'lister-item-content'})
    # print(str(i) + '.')

    header = x.findChild('h3', attrs={'class': 'lister-item-header'})
    print(str(i) + '.' + header.findChild('a').text)

    i += 1
```